# how to prove that this recursive sequence converges?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Hello this is my first time writing here so please excuse me if I did any formatting errors

given the sequence :

$a_1 = 1$

$a_{n+1} = \frac{6}{1+a_n}$

how do I prove that the sequence converges?
I know that I need to prove that the sequence is bounded and monotonic.

I succeeded in showing that for every n: $1 ≤ a_n ≤ 3$

but I notice that sequence isn't monotonic because

$a_1= 1$

$a_2 = 3$

$a_3 = 1.5$

$a_4 = 2.4$

$a_5 = 1.76470$

it goes up and down but you can see it converges to 2, so how do I prove it ?

I tried to show that all the even elements ($a_2, a_4, ...$) are decreasing and all the odd elements are increasing but I got stuck.
I'll be happy for any sort of help, please

Comment: Did you mean sequence instead of series?

Comment: Perhaps you could show $g(x)=f(f(x))$ is monotonic for $0<x \le 2$

Comment: Since you know the limit is $2$, it may be easier to consider the sequence $b_n = a_n - 2$.

Comment: Hint:  if $f$ is your function, then $f^2(x)=f\circ f(x)=\frac {6(x+1)}{x+7}$.  Analyze the behavior of that function (where is it fixed?, for which positive $x$ is $f^2(x)>x$ or $<x$?)

Comment: " I know that I need to prove that the sequence is bounded and monotonic." Well clearly not: as you (OP) yourself have noted, the sequence is not monotonic. Yes it is true that *if* a sequence is bounded and monotonic then it is convergent. But since your sequence is not monotonic you cannot quote this theorem, so you need another approach. See my answer for a correct approach, and I'm sure there are others approaches also.

Comment: Incidentally, it's also possible to find an explicit general formula for $a_n$ and then show that formula has limit 2.  This would be related to diagonalizing $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 6 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ to find the iterated powers of the projective transformation $x \mapsto \frac{6}{x+1}$.

Answer (score 1):

$a_{n+2} = \frac{6(a_n + 1)}{a_n + 7}\ \forall\ n,\ a_2 > 2,\ $ and $\ a_3 < 2.\ $ We split into two cases: even $\ n\ $ and odd $\ n.\ $ Suppose $\ n\ $ is even and $\ a_n>2.\ $ Then,

$$ a_{n+2} - 2 = \frac{6a_n + 6 - 2a_n - 14}{a_n + 7} $$

$$ = \frac{4(a_n - 2)}{a_n + 7} > 0\qquad \text{ because } a_n - 2 > 0 \text{ and } a_n +7 > 0. $$

This proves that $\ a_{n+2} > 2.\ $ Furthermore,

$$ a_{n+2} - 2 = \frac{4(a_n - 2)}{a_n + 7} < \frac{4(a_n - 2)}{2 + 7} \qquad ( \text{since } a_n>2 ) $$

$$ = \frac{4}{9} (a_n - 2). $$

This proves that, under the assumption that $n$ is even and $a_n > 2,$ then $\ 0 < a_{n+2} - 2 < \frac{4}{9} (a_n-2).$

Since $\ 2\ $ is even and $\ a_2 > 2\ $ (so basis case is true), it follows by induction that $\ 0 < a_{n+2} - 2 < \frac{4}{9} (a_n - 2)\ $ for all even $\ n,\ $ which implies that $\ 0 < (a_{2+2n} - 2) < \left(\frac{4}{9}\right)^n (a_2 - 2)\ $ for all $\ n\in\mathbb{N}.\ $ Therefore $\ \displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_{2n}-2) = 0, \implies\ \displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} a_{2n}= 2.$

Odd $n$ can be dealt with similarly, and I have left this as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

> all the even elements ($a_2, a_4, ...$) are decreasing and all the odd elements are increasing

Hint: $\,a_{n+1} - a_n = \frac{6}{1+a_n} - \frac{6}{1+a_{n-1}} = \frac{-6(a_n-a_{n-1})}{(1+a_n)(1+a_{n-1})}\,$ so $\,a_{n+1}-a_n\,$ changes sign at each step.

Answer (score 0):

We need slightly tighter bounds than you already proved: we have that $a_2=3\geq \frac{3}{2}$. Then $3 \geq a_{n}\geq \frac{3}{2}$ implies

$$a_{n+1}=\frac{6}{1+a_n}\leq \frac{6}{1+3/2}=\frac{12}{5}\leq 3$$

$$a_{n+1}=\frac{6}{1+a_n}\geq  \frac{6}{1+3}=\frac{3}{2}$$

We conclude by induction that $a_n\geq \frac{3}{2}$ for $n\geq 2$. Set $b_n=|a_n-2|$. Then

$$b_{n+1}=|a_{n+1}-2|=\left|\frac{6}{1+a_n}-2\right|=\frac{2|2-a_n|}{1+a_n}=\frac{2}{1+a_n}b_n\leq \frac{4}{5}b_n$$

But by induction this gives us that

$$b_n\leq \left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^{n-2}$$

Thus, $b_n$ converges to $0$ and therefore $a_n$ converges to $2$.